Amazon Connect Chat POC
I got the below code from the Amazon portal for a chat. When I add the component to the community page I get the below error. I have loaded 2 JS files in static resource and made that public. I need help in fixing this issue.

I got the code from this portal.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/enable-chat-in-salesforce-experience-cloud-with-amazon-connect/

<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
        <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.AmazonConnectChatInterface,$Resource.ACChat)}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
        <aura:attribute name="instanceId" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="contactFlowId" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="APIGateway" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="InitiationIcon" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="Region" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="PrimaryColor" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="ChatForm" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="Description" type="String" />
        <div id="root"></div>
    </aura:component>

Error:


Do you have LWS enabled? Or are you on Locker Service?

@FelixvanHove yes Locker Service is on.

I'd try with LWS enabled. This gives you a much better chance your Javascript is executed.

@FelixvanHove are you saying try in LWR Site?

Lightning Web Security is a different runtime security model. Have a look at the link above. If you are on a Sandbox, you can quickly exchange it for Locker Service by ticking a checkbox under Setup - Security - Session Settings. In order to switch from Locker to LWS on production, you should do some testing. There's much more information on pages related to the linked one. Most not-extremely-complex sites move over or are already on LWS these days.
